# How to set RxTimeInterval for debounce in RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rx-swift

Unable to set Rxtimeinterval for debounce in rxswift. My code is below. I got this error message "Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'RxTimeInterval' (aka 'DispatchTimeInterval')"

```
searchBar
    .rx.text // Observable property thanks to RxCocoa
    .orEmpty // Make it non-optional
    .debounce(0.5, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance) // Wait 0.5 for changes.
    .distinctUntilChanged() // If they didn't occur, check if the new value is the same as old.
    .filter { !$0.isEmpty }
```

error message:

> "Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'RxTimeInterval' (aka 'DispatchTimeInterval')"

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
searchBar
    .rx.text // Observable property thanks to RxCocoa
    .orEmpty // Make it non-optional
    .debounce(.milliseconds(500), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance) // Wait 0.5 for changes.
    .distinctUntilChanged() // If they didn't occur, check if the new value is the same as old.
    .filter { !$0.isEmpty }
```

Answer (score 10):

**Change this line:**

```
.debounce(0.5, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
```

**To this line:**

```
.debounce(RxTimeInterval.milliseconds(500), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
```

Answer (score 2):

> "Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'RxTimeInterval' (aka 'DispatchTimeInterval')"

**I got the same error and i just added this:**

`.debounce(RxTimeInterval.milliseconds(500), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)`

**instead of this** `.debounce(0.5, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)`

---

Just make sure your value in `milliseconds(<value>)` is an int